# Django combine Q object with order_by

Tags: python, django, django-q

I'm trying to abstract all the filtering logic of a form `SearchForm(forms.Form)` in a function called `get_filters`.

`get_filters` returns a Q object which is then used by the view to filter the actual queryset. As such, `get_filters` doesn't **and mustn't** know anything about the queryset: its job is just that of returning a filter which can be passed to `.filter()`

views.py:

```
def my_view(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)

    if form.is_valid():
        filters = form.get_filters()
        Model.objects.filter(filters)
```

forms.py:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Fields...
    """
    def get_filters(self):
        """
        filtering logic
        """
        return Q(some_filters)
```

This works fine. However, I now need an "order by" field.

Can I do that with Q objects in the `get_filters` function? Or I have no way other than breaking this programming pattern and access `form.cleaned_data` in the view?

Comment: The question really is should it? You've labeled the method get filters so adding ordering would only muddy that objective

Answer (score 1):

Instead of get_filter doing the order_by, can you have the view do it?

```
from my_app.models import Project
filters = get_filters(form)
ps = Project.objects.order_by('name').filter(filters)
```